# Create new columns with same value of another column of pandas dataframe, and after put 1 in the corresponding column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with pandas dataframe and I'm having a problem. I have a column named "status" and it may have 3 values, that are "married", "single" and "divorced". I want to change this dataframe creating 3 columns, that are "status married", "status single" and "status divorced". If in line 2, for example, the status is "married", the column "status married" receives number one and the another columns of this line receives 0. How can I do it in python? This solution has to be generic. Ps.: I'm sorry for my english, I hope you understand.

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df, df.status.str.get_dummies()], axis=1)`

Comment: I forgot to say that this solution has to be fast. My excel has more than 200000 lines.